# PIP package installation failed

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I tried to install lost packages by python code as follows.

```
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except ImportError:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain

try:
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
except ImportError:
    pipmain(['install', 'flask', '--no-cache-dir'])

try:
    from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
except ImportError:
    pipmain(['install', 'flask-cors', '--no-cache-dir'])

try:
    from pony.orm import *
except ImportError:
    pipmain(['install', 'pony', '--no-cache-dir'])

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    pipmain(['install', 'psycopg2', '--no-cache-dir'])
```

first package is installed successfully. But, during installation of other packages, the following error is presented.

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\mahyar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-4k0r0y0l\\0a7b803e3382957ae56f10405258ccfa40023569f7a352a5aad0f489'
```

Is there solution to solve that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't do this. The only supported interface to pip is the command-line interface, it has no public API for installing packages from *within* an existing runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code as follows:

```
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except ImportError:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain

try:
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
    from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
    from pony.orm import *
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    pipmain(['install', 'flask', 'pony', 'flask-cors', 'psycopg2'])
```

And it works well!